# java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring Boot project.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Java Spring Boot Example</name>
  <parent>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>  
</parent>    
<dependencies>  
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
    </dependency> 

    </dependencies>  
<properties>  
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>  
</properties>  
</project>
```

SpringBootExample.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class SpringBootExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExample.class, args);  
    }
}
```

When trying to execute the above class as a Java application I get an error:

> 2017-06-21 17:07:14.125 ERROR 7860 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@63f509: startup date [Wed Jun 21 17:07:06 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at SpringBootExample.main(SpringBootExample.java:12) [classes/:na]
>
> 2017-06-21 17:07:14.130 ERROR 7860 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [SpringBootExample]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
>       at SpringBootExample.main(SpringBootExample.java:12) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'errorPageFilter' for bean class [org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:268) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
>       ... 13 common frames omitted

Comment: I also faced same issue. the file applicationeventmulticaster resides inside spring-context.x.x.jar. this issue is due to multiple dependencies added in the class path of the spring-context.x.x.jar. After skipping or overriding one of them in pom fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this:

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
```

Or if you already have it comment this ( in this case i was using intellij debug button configuration) This project to be exact ([GitHub petClinicSpringBoot](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-rest))

```
<!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
```

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to the webapp project and it works now. It is part of the steps of packaging executable jar and war files following the official [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging). So make sure to complete all necessary steps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I want to deploy the war file to tomcat, so I set the spring-boot-stater-tomcat's scope as provided which means the project will use tomcat's dependency. So when you turn back to run on your machine, that will cause errors.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        ***<scope>provided</scope>***[don't need]
</dependency>
```